# Effective Cartier divisor is an open property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, divisors

Let $X$ be a regular affine $\mathbb{C}$-scheme, $A$ a (finitely-generated) $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Let $Y \subset X \times \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ be a closed subscheme of codimension $1$ such that for each $t \in \mbox{Spec}(A)$, the fiber $Y_t$ is an effective Cartier divisor of $X \times \{t\}$. Is $Y$ flat over $\mbox{Spec}(A)$? In other words, does fiberwise Cartier imply globally Cartier?

Comment: Laurent Moret-Bailly already answered your question.  I am just repeating his second counterexample, since you seem not to have understood his point.  Let $X$ be $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ with coordinate $s$, let $A$ be $k[t]$, and let $Y$ be the closed subscheme with defining ideal $\langle s^2,st \rangle$.  The fiber $Y_t$ is an effective Cartier divisor in $X\times\{t\}$ for every $t$ in $\text{Spec}\ A$.  However, $Y$ is not flat over $\text{Spec}\ A$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that "scheme" means $\mathbb{C}$-scheme, and that the product is over $\mathbb{C}$. I also assume that $Y$ is a closed subscheme.

First (trivial) counterexample: take for $Y$ an effective Cartier divisor in $X\times t$ ($t\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)(\mathbb{C})$), viewed as a subscheme of $X\times \mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

Second counterexample: if $X$ is a regular *curve*, every proper closed subscheme of $X$ is a Cartier divisor in $X$. So, take for $Y$ any closed subscheme not containing any fiber component, and not flat over $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$.